# Clear default <progress> "ease" in IE11 / EDGE

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, progress

```
<progress value="50" max="200"></progress>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4xqetber/

When we change the "value" in most browsers it changes its visual instantaneously, but on IE11 / EDGE it has an easing effect.

If we iterate on the "velue" very quickly it gets very awkward and sometimes we don't see it happen at all.

How can I make this behave like FF or Chrome?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: In theory, using the `::ms-fill` pseudo-element should allow you to remove the animation, but I'm not seeing it work in practice. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772236(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Tried that too, without success :)

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have a built in stylesheet to make certain elements look and behave in different ways. An easy way to check what styles are being applied in Edge is to go into the F12 dev tools, open up the Elements pane, select the element you want to know more about (the `progress` one, in this case), and finally go to the `Computed` tab on the right hand side of the Styles pane to see all styles that are being applied to that element.

In this case, you will find that the `transition-property` is set to `all`. Therefore, setting

```
progress {
 transition-property: none 
}
```

gets you the behavior you are looking for